# SharePoint workbench webpart size is different compared to website

Tags: vue.js, sharepoint, size, web-parts, workbench

I've written a webpart in Vue.js where the user can write a lot of information. When I tested the webpart in my SharePoint workbench it seemed to look fine.

However, when I deployed the .sppkg file to the SharePoint site, the size of the webpart changed and I couldn't click on `Create` or `Cancel` anymore.

If I change the `height`, I can't scroll down. Is there a way to fix this?

```
AddAthleticTestDialog: function() {
  var SelectedPlayerID = this.$store.state.selectedPlayer.ID;
  var $this = this;
  this.$modal.show(
    AddAthleticTest,
    {
      text: SelectedPlayerID
    },
    {
      draggable: true,
      width: 1200,
      height: 700
    },
    {
      closed: function(event) {
        $this.loadHistory(SelectedPlayerID);
      }
    }
  );
},
```

Here's how it's shown in the workbench:

[image: Workbench]

And here's how it's shown when I upload it on the webpage:

[image: Website]

Here's a small part of the code:

```
<template>
  <div class="container p-3">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" style="width:200px; padding-left:0;padding-right:0">Antropo.</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <label for="exampleInputAthletes">Athletes</label>
        <input  v-model="athleticsData.Athletes"  type="text" class="form-control" id="Athletes" placeholder="Enter Athletes" />
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <label for="exampleInputTestingDay">Testing Day</label>
        <input v-model="athleticsData.TestingDay" type="text" class="form-control" id="TestingDay" placeholder="Enter Testing Day" />
      </div>
```